# Make popup have smart positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a piece of legacy code for a table. In certain cells, I'm adding a notice icon. When you hover over the icon a `<span>` is made visible displaying some information. I would like to be able to make this `<span>` smart about its positioning but can't figure out a good method. I can statically position it but depending on which cell in the table it is in it gets lost against the edge of the page. I have done a JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nhoughto5/k78af0un/) demonstrating the issue. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use anything but HTML, CSS and vanilla JS.

The title attribute to most tags is pretty smart about its position. I have added a title to one of the cells in the table in the jsFiddle (cell containing "Hello"). Is there any way to make my span exhibit the same smart behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pop-up can be added before any element by putting the popup html code inside a 'div' with 'position:absolute; overflow:visible; width:0; height:0'.

When these events: 'onmouseenter', 'onmouseleave' are fired on the element, just toggle the popup css attribute 'display' between 'none' and 'block' of the element.

Example on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/johnlowvale/mfLhw266/

HTML and JS:

```
<div class="popup-holder">
  <div class="popup" id="popup-box">Some content</div>
</div>
<a href="javascript:" onmouseenter="show_popup()" onmouseleave="hide_popup()">Some link</a>

<script>
  function show_popup() {
    var e = $("#popup-box");
    e.css("display", "block");
  }

  function hide_popup() {
    var e = $("#popup-box");
    e.css("display", "none");
  }

</script>
```

CSS:

```
.popup-holder {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.popup {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  display: none;
}
```